# How do I add extra targets in Xcode templates?

Tags: xcode

I have created a project template and added several files and configurations to this template. I would also like to add additional targets and be able to add files to these targets. How do I proceed with making this?

Comment: Xcode templates are poorly documented, so if you have some examples how to create those lots of people will be interested (that is why you have so many votes and no answers so far). Please share more details if you can.

Comment: I found this project on GitHub that appears to do exactly that, https://github.com/vokal/Xcode-Template/blob/master/Vokal-Cocoa%20Touch%20Application%20Base.xctemplate/TemplateInfo.plist -- what have you tried that didn't work so far?